# Rotate object around a fixed coordinate axis

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, rotations

I am trying to let the user of my app rotate a $3D$ object drawn in the center of the screen by dragging their finger on screen. A horizontal movement on screen means rotation around a fixed Y axis, and a vertical movement means rotation around the X axis. The problem I am having is that if I just allow rotation around one axis the object rotates fine, but as soon as I introduce a second rotation the object doesn't rotate as expected.

Here is a picture of what is happening:

[image]

The blue axis represents my fixed axis. Picture the screen having this fixed blue axis. This is what I want the object to rotate in relation to. What is happening is in red.

Here's what I know:

The first rotation around $Y (0,1,0)$ causes the model to move from the blue space (call this space $A$) into another space (call this space B)
Trying to rotate again using the vector $(0,1,0)$  rotates around the $x$ axis in space B NOT in space $A$ which is not what I mean to do.

Here's what I tried to fix this, given what I (think) I know (leaving out the W coord for brevity):

1. First rotate around $Y (0, 1, 0)$ using a Quaternion.
2. Convert the rotation Y Quaternion to a Matrix.
3. Multiply the inverse of the $Y$ rotation matrix by my fixed axis $x$ Vector $(1, 0, 0)$ to get the fixed $X$ axis in relation to the new space.
4. Rotate around this new X Vector using a Quaternion.

This isn't working how I expect. The rotation seems to work, but at some point horizontal movement doesn't rotate about the $Y$ axis, it appears to rotate about the $Z$ axis.

I'm not sure if my understanding is wrong, or if something else is causing a problem. I have some other transformations I'm doing to the object besides rotation. I move the object to the center before applying rotation. I rotate it using the matrix returned from my function above, then I translate it -2 in the Z direction so I can see the object.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you approach the problem? What exactly are you using?

Comment: @Olivier I posted a more detailed version of the question [here](http://bit.ly/1xkOFJo)

Comment: Has it not been answered?

Comment: Nope. I've asked on Reddit, Unity Answers, Game Dev stack, and here. No answer, at least not an acceptable one that actually answers my question.

Comment: I don't think your question is clear enough. What *exactly* is your input information and what do you want to achieve? What *exactly* have you done so far? A rotation is done about an axis and with a given angle. How do you calculate those two things given the user input?

Comment: I'm trying to apply multiple rotations to an object in 3D space relative to a fixed coordinate axis. The problem is applying the first rotation moves the local coordinate space, so a second rotation is about that space and not the fixed space I intend. See the pic (blue is fixed space, red is first rotation, yellow is second etc.).

Comment: Have no idea what your problem is, but I know for sure that user interaction with rotating objects has been implemented correctly within the Advanced Visual Systems company: [AVS Express](http://www.avs.com/solutions/express/) . Maybe ask them for a demo or free trial, just to see how it works.

Comment: Why not rotate (infinitesimally) around a _fixed axis_ instead of a fixed _coordinate_ axis?

Comment: Your nice animation shows 3 rotations, with 9 vectors. Which are X and Y?  You should be able to just keep multiplying the object's current quaternion by the new finger-swipe quaternion, and it should work.  The problem is unlikely to be in your other transformations.  It looks like using a quaternion for step 1 is a waste of time since you could directly get the result of step 2 with a sin and cos.  Then steps 3 and 4 seem to be the source of your problem -- rotating around the **rotated X axis** (red) is exactly what you don't like. Just rotate around the standard X axis (blue).

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to implement a virtual trackball. Perhaps take a look at [existing formulations that people have studied](http://www.diku.dk/~kash/papers/DSAGM2002_henriksen.pdf)?

Comment: I like you animation+1

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to frame of reference. Your global frame is A and other frames obtained after rotation in A are local frames (such as B). So u want all your rotations in global frame but they are taking place in local frame. For rotation in global frame of reference you need to pre-multiply the transformation matrix and for rotation in local frame, post-multiply. For eg, if u want rotation by $\theta_1$ in A for which transformation matrix is $R_{\theta_1}$ and then rotation by $\theta_2$ in A (rotation matrix $R_{\theta_2}$), then:
$$V_f = R_{\theta_2}*R_{\theta_1}*V_i$$
where $V_i$ is initial position of the point(or object) and $V_f$ is final.
for further reference, check this link:
[Maths - frame-of-reference for combining rotations](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/for/)